# Office 365: How to handle Clutter sorting for enterprise email?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

### Overview:

I am looking to determine the best practice approach to managing Office 365's Clutter feature in a decent sized enterprise in Office 365.  The intention is to provide a solution that allows users flexibility, but allows administrative control to bypass Clutter handling for some "mission critical" messages.

### Requirements:

- Do not turn it off for everyone.  This is a poor approach to feature releases in a SaaS model such as O365.
- Some third-party services are used by the enterprise, and some of these messages must not be subject to Clutter handling. (Think: benefits providers, company surveys)
- Users retain ability to manage their own Clutter through client access (OWA), or disable entirely in Settings.

#### Additional Consideration:

- Interoperability with legacy mail systems, Clutter must not step on messages from legacy or hybrid mail environment. (This probably comes into Exchange on a separate connector.)

Comment: Yes, I am totally developing my own answer, around Transport Rules and the Clutter header stamp.  I'm looking for ideas on how to approach this as I am looking at multiple rules to handle bypass by sender, intra-org, and/or other criteria.  I don't *think* a single-rule approach will fit.

Comment: Just one admin's answer: I turned it off completely and periodically run the powershell script to turn it off for everyone just to make sure. I have yet to have a user come to me saying they want clutter turned on and are annoyed it's off, and we've had several users ask where all their mail is when it was in the clutter folder. For our users, Clutter is nothing but horrible.

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of Transport rules to force bypass of message you never want to be collected by clutter, and user awareness and training.

If users are not aware of Clutter - they will generally come to hate it and be annoyed when they can't find a message.  When they understand what it does I have  a fair amount of buy-in, and most users keep it on (a small bit will still turn it off).

I always start with one for new clients that ensure internal messages are not collected.  I used to do this only for addresses like Executives and such - but found there is the better buy in if you just leave all internal messages alone. I then layer in messages from outside services as/if needed.

Answer (score 0):

#Design:

Create up to four separate Transport rules to handle Clutter based on organizational needs.  Pick and choose as needed!

#Scenarios:

1. Bypass Clutter for intra-organizational messages
2. Bypass Clutter for Sending IP.  This covers hybrid exchange and
   legacy mail flow.
3. Bypass Clutter for explicit sender domains
4. Bypass Clutter for From Address pattern matching

#Implementation:

The action in the rule is the same in each case.  Stamp a header in the message, and let it continue on its way.

Header: `X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BypassClutter`

Value: `true`

###1.   Transport rule 1: bypass clutter for internal messages

a.   Where sender is: inside the organization

b.   Stamp header to bypass clutter

###2.   Transport Rule 2: Bypass clutter by sending IP

a.   Specify sending IP ranges or individual addresses

b.   Stamp header to bypass clutter

###3.   Transport rule 3: bypass clutter by “The Sender’s domain is” (VERY SPECIFIC)

a.   Where sender’s domain is: (list)

b.   Stamp header to bypass clutter
###4.   Transport rule 4: bypass clutter by “The sender address matches”

a.   Where FromAddressMatchesPatterns = ‘@domain.com$’

b.   REGEX, can use $ to denote end of string. Addtional stuff (partial match) should result in failure.

c.   Uses the From: field rather than the sender domain, which can be a ‘softer’ match. [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2)

d.   This one is LESS explicit and more likely to get spoofed, etc.

e.   This type may be necessary for some external services, where SenderDomainIs doesn’t catch the necessary results.

f.   Stamp header to bypass clutter.

###Sample Rule in Exchange Admin Center:

[image: Clutter Rule GUI Pattern Match]